# what is the class of jsp pages?

Tags: java, jsp

What is the class of jsp pages? I want to pass an object of page to a class whith "this" pointer on the page. How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what do you intend to do with this, but be sure you're not doing it the right way. Explain what are you trying to do exactly and why, and you'll probably get a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once they've been compiled to servlets, JSPs implement the interface `javax.servlet.jsp.JspPage`.

The actual base class depends on the servlet container, though. For example, Tomcat 6 genrated compiled JSPs extending the base class `org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase`.

Comment: I want to separate pages in to two files. A class and a jsp file. something like asp.net pages. what's your solution?

Comment: @Reza: You're talking about the MVC pattern, no?  Java has more MVC frameworks than you can count. Search stackoverflow for "java mvc".